# How to set the font size of a Canvas' text item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, text, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, font="Purisa", text= k)
```

How do I set the font size with a variable named `rndfont`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For text items, the font size is part of the `font` keyword argument:

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, font=("Purisa", rndfont), text=k)
```

Answer (score 14):

`font` is an attribute which you can pass in tkinter objects. You pass a **tuple** indicating the font *name* and *size*, so your code should look more like:

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, font=("Purisa", 12), text= k)
```

But you're asking how to make the font size a variable. You should just be able to pass it as a variable the way you would for any other use:

```
rndfont = 12
canvas.create_text(x, y, font=("Purisa", rndfont), text= k)
```

I just tested it and it seems that if you pass an invalid attribute for that tuple (like pass an empty string where the font name should be), it'll ignore the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You create the font size variable:

```
rndfont=12
```

and display the text on the canvas:

```
canvas.create_text(x,y,font=('Pursia',rndfont),text=k)
```

The font parameter can be a tuple with the font name, font size, and the special effect(bold, italic...), such as:

```
font=('Arial',30,'bold italic')
```

Comment: If you don't need the variable, you can also do font='Pursia 12'

Answer (score -3):

```
canvas.create_text(x, y, font="Purisa", size=mdfont, text=k)
```

assuming that `mdfont` is just an integer, such as

```
mdfont = 10
```

or

```
mdfont = int(raw_input("Font size? "))
```

Comment: I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Name/Desktop/Lab24.py", line 41, in <module>
    text= k)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2213, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2189, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-size"
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]